# How to check PowerShell disable by group policy using C#

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, model-view-controller

How can I fetch the details of PowerShell enabled or disabled by group policy using C#?

Comment: What mechanism are you using to disable PowerShell? From [this old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29699337/disable-cmd-and-powershell-on-windows-server-2012-for-clients) there doesn't appear to be a foolproof, PowerShell-specific way of disabling it.

Comment: Welcome to https://stackoverflow.com/. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!).

Comment: I have to run a window application to check on servers whether group policies are restricting current user from running the application or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limitation called `ExecutionPolicy`, setting, which can prevent from running scripts from files.

From C#, you can create an instance of `InitialSessionState` with `ExecutionPolicy = ByPass` and [create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.create) Powershell with this initial session state. Then try to run your script file with `Invoke-Command -FilePath`  [command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.powershell.addparameter).